# JavaScript возвращает NaN при использовании Math.sqrt()

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, по какой причине при использовании данной формулы `x=300*Math.sqrt(1-(y*y/40000));` переменная x возвращает NaN, и так происходит несколько раз, потом начинает возвращать число.

```js
var x=0;
      var y=300;
      var timer = setInterval(function(){
          y--;
          x=300*Math.sqrt(1-(y*y/40000));
          pig.style.left = x+"px";
          pig.style.top = y+"px";
      }, 10);
```

```css
      *{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
      }
      .block {
        width:600px;
        height:600px;
        background:Teal;
      }
      #pig {
        position:absolute;
        width:20px;
        height:20px;
        background:red;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="pig"></div>
    <div class="block">
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NaN` (квадратный корень из отрицательного числа) возвращается пока `y * y` не станет меньше `40000`. То есть пока `y` не уменьшится до `200`. То есть первые сто раз или, примерно, в течение первой секунды.

> А почему нельзя больше 40000 ?

Потому что

```
y = 300;
x=300*Math.sqrt(1-(y*y/40000));

y*y/40000 = 90000 / 40000 = 2.25
1 - 2.25 = -1.25
Sqrt(-1.25) = NaN
```